# Is the "Contains" Delphi string helper case sensitive?

Tags: string, delphi, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

Delphi XE3 introduced a *Contains* string helper function, but the help-file/[wiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Contains) does not state whether it is case sensitive or not?

Comment: From the [help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Contains) you are referring to: `This function is case-sensitive`.

Comment: @LU RD, I was sure that help page did not mention it when I've posted the question! Just to confirm if I was not mistaken, I've checked my TimeSnapper screenshots and yes, at 11:53 Sydney time the page did not mention the case-sensitivity :-) See http://imgur.com/ljMSt8m 

I see at the bottom of the mentioned help page "This page was last modified on 11 May 2015, at 19:40" so someone must have updated a short while ago :-)
http://imgur.com/ny7NRM1

XE7 and earlier was not updated...
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Contains

Comment: User "Adap krw" has updated that page. Change history: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/e/index.php?title=System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Contains&curid=194341&diff=712426&oldid=441046

Comment: Wow, someone is actually updating the docs, and seems to be reacting on SO posts :-)

Comment: Wow indeed, I was pretty surprised as well

Answer (score 4):

**Yes it is case sensitive.**

Quick test:

```
ShowMessage('TEST'.Contains('t').ToString(TUseBoolStrs.True));
```

returns False

---

Use [ToLowerInvariant](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.ToLowerInvariant) or [ToUpperInvariant](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.ToUpperInvariant) to compare case insensitive:

```
ShowMessage('TEST'.ToLowerInvariant.Contains('t').ToString(TUseBoolStrs.True));
```

Comment: Invariant casing is just one way. Perhaps locale sensitive would be needed for some applications.