# How to check if a string contains a substring in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

```
String content = "Jane";
String container = 'A.Sven,G.Jane,Jack'; // This is the string which i need to be searched with string content
```

`boolean containerContainsContent = StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(container, content); // I used to write like this in java`

I am new to *Delphi*. Is there a `contains` command in *Delphi* or any other command which performs the same operation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180634/is-the-contains-delphi-string-helper-case-sensitive if s.ToUpper.Contains(a.ToUpper) then

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use the functions in `StrUtils` in *Delphi*

```
uses
  StrUtils;
..
    if ContainsText('A.Sven,G.Jane,Jack', 'Jane') then 
    ...
```

`ContainsText` returns `true` if the subtext is found, without case-sensitivity, in the given text

In `StrUtils` you'll also find handy functions like `StartsText`, `EndsText` and `ReplaceText`

Comment: Thanks, I am using like 
  if Pos(content , container ) > 0  then
    showmessage('exists')
  else
    showmessage('Not exists'); 
But is there any other way

Comment: I don't understand your question, because so it would in Java

Comment: @delsql You are making something of a mess of this. Please don't ask new questions in comments to answers. If you want something different from `containsIgnoreCase` then, that would be a new question.

Comment: FWIR ContaintsText in Delphi 7 (mentioned by the topic starter ) only works for LATIN-1 characters set. If @delsql wants to compare some national characters (Greek, Russian, etc) he should use `AnsiContainsText` instead

Comment: For the ContainsText function, the needle is the 2nd parameter, not the first. For this example:
if ContainsText('A.Sven,G.Jane,Jack', 'Jane') then

Answer (score 6):

You might also find helpful the `Contains` Function in `System.SysUtils` as below.

```
uses
  Sysytem.SysUtils;

....
  txt := 'This is a string variable';

  if txt.contains('str') then
....
```